# Program[Digikam] chooses wrong qt lib and crashes

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, digikam

I run Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. Digikam used to work but recently stopped working.

I was wondering if someone could help me work a way to resolve this issue.

I've had a response from the Digikam mailing list to say that this is not really a Digikam issue but an issue on my system where there is some conflict with Qt4 and Qt5. The stack trace below shows Digikam crashing on a Qt5 lib, but it is only programmed with Qt4.

Any suggestions?

```
apt-cache policy digikam
digikam:
  Installed: 4:3.5.0-0ubuntu10
  Candidate: 4:3.5.0-0ubuntu10
  Version table:
 *** 4:3.5.0-0ubuntu10 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


gdb digikam
Reading symbols from digikam...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/89/8c66e5a3a2b8dce7156f7e8c1698e4bd29ef9d.debug...done.
done.
(gdb) catch throw
Catchpoint 1 (throw)
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/digikam 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:286
286 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __strcmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:286
#1  0x00007fffdf31609e in QMetaType::registerNormalizedType(QByteArray const&, void (*)(void*), void* (*)(void const*), void (*)(void*), void* (*)(void*, void const*), int, QFlags<QMetaType::TypeFlag>, QMetaObject const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007fffdeb0b7b7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff7dea13a in call_init (l=<optimised out>, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffdf38, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffdf48) at dl-init.c:78
#4  0x00007ffff7dea223 in call_init (env=<optimised out>, argv=<optimised out>, argc=<optimised out>, l=<optimised out>) at dl-init.c:36
#5  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe1c8, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf38, env=0x7fffffffdf48) at dl-init.c:126
#6  0x00007ffff7ddb30a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#7  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fffffffe29c in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 10315] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

The output of the qtchooser tool

```
$ qtchooser -l
4
5
default
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
$ qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

I know that there are no libs called Qt4* in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu even though I've installed (and reinstalled) most of the libqt4 packages from the main repo.

Comment: Does this happens with the version offered by the Official Ubuntu repository?

Comment: Yes. Removing the ppa and reverting back to the official repo version which is 3.5 (very old) still crashes. I'll update the stack trace for the official repo version

Comment: Could you post output of `qtchooser -l`  and `qtchooser -print-env`

Comment: Yep, updated the original post. I'm not sure where the libqt4 files are. running locate libQt4 returns nothing, while libQt5 returns all the files in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" plus a host of app specific folders in /opt.

Comment: I looked at the package in the repos for qt4 and realised that their not prefixed with "qt4" and the files that are supposed to be installed are in fact living on my system in working order.

Comment: ?have you done sudo apt-get build-dep digikam
sudo apt-get build-dep kipi-plugins

Comment: Yes. Hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I had `opencv` installed from source sitting in `/usr/local`. Uninstalling it and removing the remaining files from `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include` fixed the broken link to qt and reinstalling `digikam` fixed everything.

The hint was check the manually installed things sitting in `/usr` in case one of them is conflicting.